# How do I maintain my SQL in separate files and pull them into Sequelize raw queries?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have my SQL working fine in a raw query, however the SQL is pretty complex, and I would like to start moving them out of the main body of code and into their own .sql files, however I'm new to this and can't work out how to reference them and get them working.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json())

router.post('/new', (req, res) =>
db.sequelize.query(`
    INSERT INTO containers
        (
            "changeId",
            "name",
            "description",
            "createdAt",
            "updatedAt", 
            "isDeleted"
        )
    VALUES 
        (
            :id, 
            'New Container',
            'Default description to be changed',
            NOW(),
            NOW(),
            false
        );
    `,
    {
        replacements: { id: req.body.id },
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
    }
)
.then(containers => {
    res.json({
        containers
    });
})
.then(console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)))
.catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

How do I pass '../sql/newcontainer.sql' in place of the SQL query that's currently there?

Note: this is obviously a very simple SQL query for the purposes of this example. There are others which are significantly longer.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use stored procedures?

Comment: Hmmm... good point...